# Error Con iis Express!

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2015, iis

Al intentar pasar un proyecto completo a otra PC, cuando lo ejecute, me da este error!
ya Intente cambiar El puerto en Propiedades/Web y aun sigue con el mismo problema.
[image: Error de iis Express web server]

Comment: muestra tu webconfig :)

Comment: Ya fue Solucionado mi hermano Gracias por la intención de igual modo!

Comment: cheeere! de nada hermano, somos la hermandad de SOes, entre todos aprendemos, entre todos crecemos :D sigue con todo el power 2.0!!!  Éxitos con el desarrollo :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Junto con tu archivo **.SLN** generalmente existe una carpeta oculta llamada **.vs**, borrala.

Para hacerlo sigue estos pasos:

1. Cierra Visual Studio
2. Borra la carpeta
3. Ejecuta Visual Studio e intenta correr de nuevo tu programa.

En esa carpeta se guardan configuraciones del IIS Express que cuando se mueven de un equipo a otro, pueden causar el problema que estas teniendo.

Comment: Asi mismo Era mi hermano Gracias! Funciono!

Answer (score 1):

si cambiando  la nombre de carpeta de iisespres  que esta
C:\Usuarios\TuNombre\Documentos\IISExpress  y cierras visual studio crea una carpeta nueva automaticamente ya vuelve funcionar esto hize con visual studio 2017

Comment: Bienvenido!!! por favor mira [answer] para hacer una respuesta de mejor calidad.

Answer (score 0):

Borra o renombra la carpeta que se crea automaticamente del IISExpress en C:\Usuarios\TuNombre\Documentos\IISExpress
Cuando corras la aplicacion, Visual Studio vuelve a crearla y te deberia funcionar

Comment: Es que nisiquiera crea la carpeta por que en un proyecto que estoy pasando de otra PC.

Comment: intenta deshabilitando el firewall de tu equipo e intentando nuevamente correr la aplicacion

Comment: me parece raro, porque IISExpress crea una carpeta en mis documentos, seguro que no tienes esa carpeta en tu nuevo pc?

Comment: La carpeta que dices si esta pero no esta el proyecto que quiero abrir.

Comment: intentaste deshabilitando el firewall?

Answer (score 0):

tuve  este error en visual studio  2017 y  2019,

este error trata sobre los puertos asp.net  que no estan funcionado bien

Ejemplo estos puerto que miran aquí 
    http://localhost:55399

debe realizar posicionarme sobre el proyecto darle clic derecho, ir hasta del modal 
y darle clic a propiedades. en este momento se abrirá configuraciones. y le damos clic en depurar bajos un poco. Encontraremos  dirección Url de la aplicación entoces debilitamos  la opción habilitar SSL y en  dirección Url  realizamos el cambio de puertos.

Como hacemos el cambio  de puertos creamos nuevo proyecto  asp.net. Realizamos el mismo proceso anterior y copiamos toda la dirección url que nos aparezca en el  proyecto nuevo y lo copiamos en el otro proyecto  del problema y  asi  solucionado el error.

[image: Este las propiedades de proyecto]

Espero que les funcione.